# JRuby on Rails 3.2.2 on Heroku

Tags: heroku, jruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jrubyonrails

I have a mature Rails 3.2.2 app that I would like to deploy on top of JRuby on Heroku for reasons I won't go into.  After trying to bootstrap JRuby via the Maven config and unsuccessfully trying to get the Rails app to bundle, I've resorted to using a custom Heroku buildpack based on  Carl Hörberg's [JRuby buildpack for Heroku](https://github.com/jruby/heroku-buildpack-jruby), which I perceive that I'm having more success with.  The only difference between my custom buildpack and Carl's is that I don't attempt to precompile assets during slug compilation as I would prefer to do this locally.

The push to Heroku works great.  Heroku receives the push, fetches the custom buildpack, installs all the bundled gems, launches etc. with no problems, warnings, or errors but when I attempt to resolve the deployed app in the browser, I immediately get a 500 error (this is an app that runs just fine on MRI 1.9.2).  Unfortunately, the Heroku logs aren't that helpful:

```
2012-07-24T01:39:27+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-07-24T01:39:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/trinidad --threadsafe --rackup -p 9108 -e production`
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9108"]
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 24, 2012 1:39:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 24, 2012 1:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service Tomcat
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 24, 2012 1:39:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-07-24 01:39:43 INFO: No global web.xml found
2012-07-24T01:39:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-24T01:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-07-24 01:39:44 INFO: INFO: jruby 1.7.0.preview1 (ruby-1.9.3-p203) (2012-05-19 00c8c98) (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_20) [linux-amd64-java]
2012-07-24T01:39:44+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-07-24 01:39:44 INFO: INFO: using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2012-07-24T01:39:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-07-24 01:39:47 SEVERE: ERROR: unable to create shared application instance
2012-07-24T01:39:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-07-24 01:39:47 SEVERE: Error: application initialization failed
2012-07-24T01:39:47+00:00 app[web.1]: 2012-07-24 01:39:47 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9108"]
2012-07-24T01:39:49+00:00 heroku[router]: GET agile-crag-7590.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=512ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-07-24T01:39:49+00:00 heroku[router]: GET agile-crag-7590.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be wrong?  I've tried changing the JRuby version being used in the buildpack to 1.6.7 and/or disabling multithreading in the app config and Procfile, but I get roughly the same results.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If you are using logger pipe the production log to stdout instead of file.